# Two Objects in Live Data referencing each other

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, mutablelivedata

I've got two Objects (Object1 and Object2) saved via Android Room, which I want to access using **LiveData**. `Object1` contains a reference to `Object2`.

```
public class Object1 {

...

private Object2 object2;

...

}
```

I want to pass a `LivaData<List<Object1>>` containing all my Objects from the ViewModel to the Activities, each `Object1` already heaving stored the reference to the matching `Object2` (Object1 stores the Id of Object2 in the Database).

What is the best way to combine the objects? I found **MediatorLiveData** and **MutableLiveData** but couldn't find an example that seemed useful for my case.

*Edits:*
About the whole situation: `Object1` is some data I'm loading from the web and caching via Android Room. `Object2` is some additional data which users can save locally, always concerning the data from one specific `Object1`. So every `Object2` is related to an `Object1` but not every `Object1` has an `Object2`. Finally I want to pass an Object to the UI, containing all the data from the web and (if there is any) all additional data, users added to it.

The problem: I don't know what's the most efficient way to match the data from two different data sources in a way that the **LiveData** always updates when one of them is changed.

Thanks for helping me out whilst learning Android

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "combine the objects".  Please edit the question to be more descriptive of what problem you're running into and your final goal.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks. I've edited my question, hopefully everything is clear now

Comment: If you are using Room, then you should be using a JOIN  via @Embedded to get a combined object.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks's a lot, that solved my problem!